# How to login to ASP.NET Core Web App with default Individual Accounts from code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I’m trying to set up Integration tests (from API to database), and I’m having trouble finding a way to test controllers that *require authorization*.

We’re using out-of-box individual accounts with SQL Server – cookie-based auth.

What is the easiest way to set up integrations tests – for testing with actual users/passwords? I don’t want to mock anything.

**I’m having trouble emulating user login action and getting token.**

Many articles discuss custom startup classes, mocks, in-memory databases, custom authentication, tokens, emulating users, etc. Like this one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/test-aspnet-core-services-web-apps

But, I would like to keep it as close as possible to production code/settings.